# php session numeric variables not saved properly to other scripts

Tags: php, session

When assigning numeric values (latitude and longitude values) to $_SESSION variables the values are stored correctly on the original script. However, when a 2nd page accesses the $_SESSION variables the value is now the name of the variable. See below.

page1.php code

```
<?
php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>

var latitude = 35.0;
    var longitude = -89.0;

<?php
$_SESSION['wailat'] = latitude;
$_SESSION['wailng'] = longitude;
?>

<p>Latitude is ' + <?php echo $_SESSION['wailat']; ?> <br>Longitude is <?php echo $_SESSION['wailng']; ?></p>

     <a href="page2.php">Page 2</a>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Page 1 output is correct:
Latitude is 35.0
Longitude is -89.0

Page 2 code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['wailat']) && isset($_SESSION['wailng']) ) { 
echo 'Latitude ' . $_SESSION['wailat'] . '<br />Longitude ' . $_SESSION['wailng'];
 } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2 output is incorrect:

Latitude is latitude
Longitude is longitude

Why do the two session variables' value on page 2 = the name of the variable that was assigned to them rather than the value?

Comment: Looks like you're mixing PHP and JavaScript which does not mix. Either that or you don't know how to write PHP as the syntax in your first snippet isn't even close to correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<?php
    $latitude = 35;
    $longitude = -89;

    $_SESSION['wailat'] = $latitude;
    $_SESSION['wailng'] = $longitude;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the variables in html body , and it will display as it is on the page .this is not the way to declare variables. no variables are being created on the page. and even on the first page it will not echo the vars.
you must do it like @peter has mentioned.